Least squares cross product equations
I've tried, unsuccessfully, to either solve or find a solution to something along lines of:
find $\bar{a}$, $\bar{b}$ nearby to some initial guess that satisfies $\bar{c} = \bar{a} \times \bar{b}$.
Setting this up as a constrained least squares problem:
Given 3 vectors $\bar{a}, \bar{b}, \bar{c}$ that satisfies $\bar{c} = \bar{a} \times \bar{b}$, and given a perturbation $\Delta \bar{c}$, then find the vectors $\Delta \bar{a}$ and $\Delta \bar{b}$ that minimize the objective function $J = \Delta \bar{a}^T\Delta \bar{a} +  \Delta \bar{b}^T\Delta \bar{b}$ such that $\bar{c} + \Delta \bar{c} =  \left(\bar{a} + \Delta \bar{a} \right) \times \left( \bar{b} + \Delta \bar{b} \right)$.
The constraint can be rewritten as: $\Delta \bar{c} = \left[ \left(\bar{a} + \Delta \bar{a} \right) \times \left( \bar{b} + \Delta \bar{b} \right) - \bar{a} \times \bar{b} \right]$.
Given a Lagrange multiplier $\bar{\lambda}$, the corresponding unconstrained least squares problem becomes:
Minimize $J = \Delta \bar{a}^T\Delta \bar{a} +  \Delta \bar{b}^T\Delta \bar{b} + \bar{\lambda}^T\left\{ \Delta \bar{c} - \left[ \left(\bar{a} + \Delta \bar{a} \right) \times \left( \bar{b} + \Delta \bar{b} \right) - \bar{a} \times \bar{b} \right] \right\}$, with optimization parameters $\bar{a}, \bar{b}$, and $\bar{\lambda}$.
Trying to solve $\frac{\partial J}{\partial \bar{a}} = \frac{\partial J}{\partial \bar{b}} = \frac{\partial J}{\partial \bar{\lambda}} = \bar{0}^T$ leads to intractable algebra as far as I can tell.  Is this problem unsolveable? or maybe there's a better approach or already a known solution?
I'm aware of a projected solution where either $\bar{a}$ or $\bar{b}$ is held constant, but in this case there's some error in the final cross product which is minimized.  By allowing both vectors to vary, hoping for an exact solution.

Was able to solve this by a slight modification to the above approach.  We know that the 2 vectors $\bar{a}$ and $\bar{b}$ are perpendicular to $\bar{c}$, so I constrained the solution space to that subspace (the null-space of $\bar{c}^T$). Using Lagrange multipliers, I eventually derived a 4th order polynomial in $\lambda$.  And using perturbation theory, came up with a very close estimate to the desired root, rather than solve the quartic.
